# contanerview color is not change when come in previews viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

i have two viewcontroller first and second when i go to secondview and dismiss and come in first viewcontroller then protcol proper working, i already got data in previous controller but not one controller title chager or not change background color of UIview.

i already set this type of method but still background color or button title was not change.

This is not complete code but example for understanding.

```
    //FirstViewcontroller
class First : UIViewController, passData {

    func test(test: ApiData) {
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    // Present secondviewcotroller from this viewcontroller
}

//SecondViewcontroller
protocol passData{
    func test(test : ApiData)
}

class Second : UIViewController {

    //Dismisss seconviewcontrolller
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegateSelectMusic.audioData = tempData
    }
}
```

i already got data when dismiss but not set in my label and button.

Comment: Does it working initially? I mean the color chnages before going to the next view controller

Comment: yes it does @MahakMittal

Comment: Please share the code which container view you are using and where method is get calling after dismissal of the second view

Comment: containerview is like a UIView. Method call on dismiss completion handler but method is proper called but when i come in firstviewcontroller from secondviewcontroller then for testing purpose i change color of firstviewcontroller its not work i do not why ?

Comment: Yes in which method you changed the first view controller color?

Comment: from protocol method i update my question with example of code.

Comment: Need complete information of how you are dismissing, presenting view controller and on what kind of objects you are setting data. does those are IBOutlets or created through code

Answer (score 0):

Follow this one.

// First View Controller

```
    // container view object 

    private var recommendationsFilterFilterVC: RecommendationsFilterViewController!

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    switch segue.identifier! {
    case "RecommendationsFilterViewController":

        self.recommendationsFilterFilterVC  = (segue.destination as! RecommendationsFilterViewController)
        self.recommendationsFilterFilterVC.delegate = self

    default:
        break
    }
}


// Call Delegate Method

//MARK: UICropProfileFilterView Delegate

extension ShowRecommendationsViewController : RecommendationsFilterDelegate {
    func hideAndShowRecommendationsFilterView(arrRecommendationFilter: [JSON]) {
        viewTranslate.isHidden = true
        containerFilterView.isHidden = true
        self.arrRecommendationList .removeAll()
        self.arrRecommendationList = arrRecommendationFilter
        self.tblRecommedationList.reloadData()
    }

 }
```

//Second View Controller

```
protocol RecommendationsFilterDelegate: class {
    func hideAndShowRecommendationsFilterView(arrRecommendationFilter:[JSON])
}
```

//MARK: Variable

```
weak var delegate: RecommendationsFilterDelegate?


@IBAction func onBack(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.hideAndShowRecommendationsFilterView(arrRecommendationFilter: object["data"]["recordDetails"].arrayValue)
}
```